# Consulta SQL não retorna mesmo tendo valores

Tags: sql

Não intendi essa

Retorna

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_temporadas WHERE serie_id = '2' AND serie_slug = 'dois-homens-e-meio' AND temp_audio = 'l'
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não retorna

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_temporadas WHERE serie_id = '2' AND serie_slug = 'dois-homens-e-meio' AND temp_audio = 'd'
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha tabela

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**CRUD**

```
private $query;

private function prep_exec($prep, $exec) {          
    $this->query = $this->get_con()->prepare($prep);
    $this->query->execute($exec);
}

public function select($fields, $table, $prep, $exec) {
    $this->prep_exec("SELECT ".$fields." FROM ".$table." ".$prep."", $exec); 
    return $this->query;
}

$open_serie = $ctlr->select("*", "tbl_seriados", "WHERE serie_slug = ?", array($sep[0]));

foreach ($open_serie as $list) :
   $serie_id = (int)$list['serie_id'];

   $open_temp_dub = $ctlr->select("*", "tbl_temporadas", "WHERE serie_id = ? AND serie_slug = ? AND temp_audio = ?", array($serie_id, 'dois-homens-e-meio', 'D'));

endforeach;
```

Comment: Tente reparar seu banco de dados.

Comment: tente deixar o id como inteiro, removendo as aspas do numero 2 SELECT * FROM tbl_temporadas WHERE serie_id = 2 AND serie_slug = 'dois-homens-e-meio' AND temp_audio = 'l'

Comment: @anonimo Não foi, estranho

Comment: @AndersonHenrique No meu codigo ja defino o id int `$serie_id = (int)$list['serie_id'];` mesmo assim não vai

Comment: Coloque seu código php também

Comment: Existe a chance de ter um espaço em branco antes do 'd'?

Comment: @goio: o que você quer dizer com "Não foi" ao tentar reparar o banco de dados?

Comment: Verdade pode ser o que o @RonaldoAraújoAlves falou, nesse caso para testar, execute essa query SELECT * FROM tbl_temporadas WHERE serie_id = '2' AND serie_slug = 'dois-homens-e-meio' AND temp_audio  LIKE '%d%'

Comment: Se retornar é porque tem espaço entre o d

Comment: @anonimo Continua a mesma coisa http://prntscr.com/nyyr75

Comment: @Anderson Henrique http://prntscr.com/nyysvg Ronaldo não tem espaços em branco

Comment: tente com as aspas denovo no número 2 usando o like, pois sua primeira query que funcionou você usou aspas

Comment: @AndersonHenrique Mesmo selecionando só o id depois o slug junto ele puxa somente os 3 primeiros http://prntscr.com/nyyvbi http://prntscr.com/nyyvom

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94653/discussion-between-anderson-henrique-and-goio).

Comment: Se a classe `$ctrl` não possuir um método de debug para printar qual query está sendo formatada, eu colocaria um `echo $sql; exit;` em algum lugar dentro de `$ctrl->select` para ver qual a query que está sendo formada.. as vezes pode estar sendo formata de forma incorreta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema está na coluna serie_slug, podendo ter algum espaço ou caracter que esteja quebrando, realize o update de todos com a query e no php o D está maiusculo

```
UPDATE tbl_temporadas SET serie_slug='dois-homens-e-meio' WHERE serie_id = 2;
```

E teste o SELECT novamente

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_temporadas WHERE serie_id = '2' AND serie_slug = 'dois-homens-e-meio' AND temp_audio = 'd'
```